# Parse XSD file to get names and descriptions

Tags: python, regex, xsd

I'm trying to parse this XSD file, currently trying in python, to snag the name of an element and the description of what the data is.

#### Example XSD:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" version="07112016">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>Level 1: top level of Procurement Data Standard for a procurement instrument document.</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:element name="ProcurementDocument">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>The root element for any procurement instrument document</xs:documentation>
```

Here It would grab `name: ProcurementDocument` and `desc:The root element for any procurement instrument document`.

[here](https://regex101.com/r/1AtwxE/1) is more data where I tried to pull it using regular expression. I had more success when I [minified](https://regex101.com/r/xPRYiu/1) it to all be on one line but still did not pull every instance.

Here is my full code I tried to use to get all the cases from my minified XSD but only found ~120 of the ~1500 I was trying to find.

```
import re
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Names': [ ], 'Description': [ ]})

search_str = r"name=\"(?P<name>\w+)\"\>[\w\<\/\.\>\d:]+documentation\>(?P<desc>[\w\s\.]+)\<\/"
file1 = 'mini_text.xml'

with open(file1, 'r') as f:
    xml_string = f.read()
idx = 0
for m in re.finditer(search_str, xml_string):
    df.loc[idx, 'Names'] = m.group('name')
    df.loc[idx, 'Description'] = m.group('desc')
    idx += 1

df.to_csv('output.txt', index=False, sep="\t")
```

Comment: Honestly, I'm of the opinion that `one can use regex to parse html/xml` situationally. Hell it can save a lot of lines and allow you avoid some of the shortfalls of other libraries. For yours you can easily use this: `>>> re.findall('<xs:element[\s]*name="([\S\s]*?)">[\S\s]*?<xs:documentation>([\S\s]*?)</xs', string)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should avoid parsing xml/html/json using regex as regex isn't capable enough parsing nested structures.

The reason why your regex doesn't capture all instances of name and description in your text is, the character set you have chosen for capturing description `[\w\s\.]+` is not enough as in description there are characters present like parenthesis `(see list)` due to which further expected matches fail. Try changing `[\w\s\.]+` to `.+?` and then it will work. Check below your updated regex101 demo link.

**[Working Demo of your modified regex](https://regex101.com/r/WtXKNi/1)**

**Edit: Sample example showing how to parse your xml using [Beautiful Soup](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/) to get the desired information**

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = '''<xs:element name="ProductDescription"><xs:annotation><xs:documentation>Provides the description of the product</xs:documentation></xs:annotation><xs:complexType><xs:sequence><xs:element name="ProductName"><xs:annotation><xs:documentation>Provides a name for the product. (see list)</xs:documentation></xs:annotation><xs:simpleType><xs:restriction base="xs:token"><xs:enumeration value="Barbie Doll"/><xs:enumeration value="Ken Doll"/></xs:restriction></xs:simpleType></xs:element><xs:element name="ProductSize"><xs:annotation><xs:documentation>Describes the size of the product. (see list)</xs:documentation></xs:annotation><xs:simpleType><xs:restriction base="xs:token"><xs:enumeration value="Small"/><xs:enumeration value="Medium"/><xs:enumeration value="Large"/><xs:enumeration value="Dayum"/></xs:restriction></xs:simpleType></xs:element></xs:sequence></xs:complexType></xs:element>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(data)

for element in soup.find_all('xs:element'):
 print(element['name'])  # prints name attribute value
 print(element.find('xs:documentation').get_text(),'\n')  # prints inner text of xs:documentation tag
```

Prints the name and description like you wanted,

```
ProductDescription
Provides the description of the product

ProductName
Provides a name for the product. (see list)

ProductSize
Describes the size of the product. (see list)
```

Comment: Seems like a dead link. Is there a more common way to parse the xsd to get this same information?

Comment: @lwileczek: Seems like the link got deleted somehow. I've updated the link again in my answer. For parsing xml you can go for [Beautiful Soup](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/)

Comment: @lwileczek: I've added sample codes showing how same information you can easily and more reliably extract using beautiful soup. Hope that helps.